# Parse a dynamic JSON object into PHP

Tags: php, json

Below is the JSON object I am trying to parse. It its basically the answers to a dynamic form. I know I can convert it to an array and then work with it. The issue I am having is the JSON object will be different every time.

```
{
"sections": [
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "element": "greeting",
                "components": {
                    "paragraph": {
                        "content": "Thank you for calling company name. This is a test call."
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-fullname",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": ""
                    },
                    "first_name": {
                        "name": "1[custom-fullname][first_name]",
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "John",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "last_name": {
                        "name": "1[custom-fullname][last_name]",
                        "label": "Last Name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "smith",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-phone",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Phone Number"
                    },
                    "phone_ext": {
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone_ext]",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    "input_format": {
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone_format]",
                        "type": "hidden",
                        "value": "standard"
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    },
                    "phone": {
                        "value": "7864564444",
                        "required": "false",
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-message",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Message"
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "name": "3[custom-message][message]",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "test time 22222",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "notes",
                "components": {
                    "paragraph": {
                        "content": "This is a test call. Please mark this as a test."
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "faqs": [
            {
                "question": "Should i have a FAQ?",
                "answer": "Yes, this will help the agent to have a fluent conversation with the caller."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "element": "greeting",
                "components": {
                    "paragraph": {
                        "content": "Thank you for calling company name. This is a test call."
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-fullname",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": ""
                    },
                    "first_name": {
                        "name": "1[custom-fullname][first_name]",
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "robert",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "last_name": {
                        "name": "1[custom-fullname][last_name]",
                        "label": "Last Name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "gonzalez",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-phone",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Phone Number"
                    },
                    "phone_ext": {
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone_ext]",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    "input_format": {
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone_format]",
                        "type": "hidden",
                        "value": "standard"
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    },
                    "phone": {
                        "value": "7864564444",
                        "required": "false",
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-message",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Message"
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "name": "3[custom-message][message]",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "Test",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "notes",
                "components": {
                    "paragraph": {
                        "content": "This is a test call. Please mark this as a test."
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "faqs": [
            {
                "question": "Should i have a FAQ?",
                "answer": "Yes, this will help the agent to have a fluent conversation with the caller."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "element": "greeting",
                "components": {
                    "paragraph": {
                        "content": "Thank you for calling company name. This is a test call."
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-fullname",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": ""
                    },
                    "first_name": {
                        "name": "1[custom-fullname][first_name]",
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "robert",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "last_name": {
                        "name": "1[custom-fullname][last_name]",
                        "label": "Last Name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "gonzalez",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-phone",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Phone Number"
                    },
                    "phone_ext": {
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone_ext]",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    "input_format": {
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone_format]",
                        "type": "hidden",
                        "value": "standard"
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    },
                    "phone": {
                        "value": "7861238975",
                        "required": "false",
                        "name": "2[custom-phone][phone]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "custom-message",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Message"
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "name": "3[custom-message][message]",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "test time 22222",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "element": "radio",
                "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Whats type of office are you looking for?"
                    },
                    "radiolist": [
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "value": "value_0",
                                "id": "single_choice_answer_0"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "content": "Dedicated Space"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "value": "value_1",
                                "id": "single_choice_answer_1"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "content": "Parttime Space"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "single_choice_answer": {
                        "value": "value_0",
                        "name": "4[radio][single_choice_answer]",
                        "required": ""
                    },
                    "help_text": {
                        "content": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "faqs": [
            {
                "question": "Should i have a FAQ?",
                "answer": "Yes, this will help the agent to have a fluent conversation with the caller."
            }
        ]
    }
]


}
```

So, for example a part of the JSON object looks like the following.

```
                    "components": {
                    "label": {
                        "content": "Whats type of office are you looking for?"
                    },
                    "radiolist": [
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "value": "value_0",
                                "id": "single_choice_answer_0"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "content": "Dedicated Space"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "value": "value_1",
                                "id": "single_choice_answer_1"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "content": "Parttime Space"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "single_choice_answer": {
                        "value": "value_0",
                        "name": "4[radio][single_choice_answer]",
                        "required": ""
                    },
```

I would like to take that and do something like the following:

```
    {
"components": {
    "label": {
        "content": "Whats type of office are you looking for?"
    },
    "answer": {
        "value": "value_0",
        "name": "Dedicated Space",
        "required": ""
    }
}
```

Really I just need the form questions and answer formatted a little nicer in a JSON object. However, I'm not sure how to code this in PHP.

Comment: Next time, try not to paste a whole bunch of confusing code. (JSON in this case) If you provide a small example, your question will be much easier to answer.

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), make your changes, then [`json_encode()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: if your JSON object graph will change then how do you expect to parse it